# Why does C=C bond replace C-O bond when two graphite platelets are rubbed against each other edge on edge?

Tags: valence-bond-theory, carbon-allotropes

When two small 2D carbon platelets are pushed into proximity, why do they release the edge attached molecule (maybe O) and then bond C to C?
I think the answer I seek would address the relative difference in bond strengths, and what forces are involved to remove attached molecules, probably Oxygen.   .....
BACKGROUND:   I experiment with electrostatic properties of conductive carbon films for oscillation and physical displacement applications. I use a mechanical 'tribological' method of creating 2D Carbon sheets.  In this case the method is: smearing powered graphite onto a smooth substrate, followed by agitation and polishing to a smooth highly conductive film.  The result is assumed to be hexagonal graphene film of several layers.